# Remove user from table using checkbox

Tags: php, mysql

I know there are questions similar, but I am unable to determine my issue with my PHP code. I am trying to remove a student from an intermediary table between Student table and Class table, called Student_has_Class. The SQL code works, just not the page. It lists the students in the table successfully, but when I check the box by a student to remove them and click submit, it redirects to same page (basically a refresh) like it is supposed to (even though it doesn't reload the table for some reason), and the student is still in the Student_has_Class table. Please help, as posting online is a last resort for me.

Please take a look a the code:

Note: I removed some login and web address info for privacy. Indicated with { }.

```
<?php

// Connects to your Database
session_start();
$x = $_SESSION['user'];
$y = $_GET['id'];
mysql_connect("{removed site for privacy}", "{username removed}", "{password removed}") or die(mysql_error
    ());
mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());

if (isset($_POST['delete']))
{
    if (isset($_POST['checkbox']))
    {
        $checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];
        if (is_array($checkbox)) {

            foreach ($checkbox as $key => $x)
            {
                $mysql->query("DELETE FROM Student_has_Class WHERE User_idUser='$x'"); 
                }
            }
        }
    }  
?>

<?php

$sql = "SELECT User.idUser, User.UserFirstName, User.UserLastName
FROM Student_has_Class
INNER JOIN User ON User.idUser = Student_has_Class.User_idUser AND User.Role = 'Student'
INNER JOIN Class ON Class.idClass = Student_has_Class.Class_idClass
WHERE Student_has_Class.Class_idClass = 2 AND Class.User_idUser = ".$x."
ORDER BY User.UserLastName";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

?>

<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td><form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="4" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Class Roster</strong> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Drop</td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>ID</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Last Name</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>First Name</strong></td>
</tr>

<?php
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ 
?>

<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="<?php echo $rows['idUser'];?>"></td>

<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['idUser'];?></td>

<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['UserLastName'];?></td>

<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['UserFirstName'];?></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>

<tr>
<td colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>

<?php

// Check if delete button active, start this
if ($_POST['delete'])
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
    {
        $del_id = $checkbox[$i];
        $sql = "DELETE FROM Student_has_Class WHERE User_idUser=".$del_id."";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
    }
    // if successful redirect to same page
    if ($result)
    {
        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL={address}/{page}.php\">";
    }
}
mysql_close();

?>
```

Update:

I used Internet Explorer debugger to get some info that Chrome debugger doesn't provide. Here is the page, notice the values in the checkboxes. I'm not sure if that is correct.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>*HIDDEN*</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
                background-color: #D9D7D7;
}
h1 {
                color: #FBF8F8;
}
</style>
<style>
table,th,td
{
border:1px solid black;
}
</style>


</head>


<body bgcolor="#D7D3D3">
<a href="main_login.php" >
<img src="banner2.jpg" width="1340" height="90">
</a></img>
<div id="shHeader">
<center>
  <div class="div"> 
Welcome to *HIDDEN*!</div></center>
<table width ="1345" height="30" align="top" border=1"> 
<tr align= top>
<tr>
<td width="40"> <a href = "PicChart.php?id="> Category </a> </td>

<td width="40"> <a href = "HWGraph.php?id="> Homework Graph </a> </td> 

<td width="40"> <a href = "TestGraph.php?id="> Test Graph </a> </td>

<td width="40"> <a href = "MainPageTabs.php?id= "> Overview Graph </a> </td>

<td width="40"> <a href = "MainPageTabs.php?id="> Progress Bar </a> </td>

<td width="40"> <a href = "MainPageTabs.php?id="> Timeline </a> </td>
</tr>





<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td><form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="4" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Class Roster</strong> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Drop</td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>ID</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Last Name</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>First Name</strong></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<input name='checkbox[0]' type='checkbox' id='checkbox[]' value=''></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">5</td>

<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">*HIDDEN*</td>

<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">*HIDDEN*</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<input name='checkbox[1]' type='checkbox' id='checkbox[]' value=''></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">3</td>

<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">*HIDDEN*</td>

<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">*HIDDEN*</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<input name='checkbox[2]' type='checkbox' id='checkbox[]' value=''></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">12</td>

<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">*HIDDEN*</td>

<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">*HIDDEN*</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<input name='checkbox[3]' type='checkbox' id='checkbox[]' value=''></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">4</td>

<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">*HIDDEN*</td>

<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">*HIDDEN*</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<input name='checkbox[4]' type='checkbox' id='checkbox[]' value=''></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">6</td>

<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">*HIDDEN*</td>

<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">*HIDDEN*</td>
</tr>

<input type='hidden' name='hiddencounter' value='5'>


<tr>
<td colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete"></td>
</tr>


</table>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>



</body>
</html>
```

Update:

The POST parameters are as follows when I try to delete the third person in the table by checking the checkbox to the left of their name, and clicking the Delete button (previously called Submit button). The person to delete has a User ID of 12.

Array ( [checkbox] => Array ( [2] => ) [hiddencounter] => 5 [delete] => Delete )

Comment: Check the POST paramters in the debug console (F12).

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL Injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: Also, if I manualy post a form with a checkbox value as `1'; DELETE FROM Student_has_Class; SELECT id FROM Student_has_Class WHERE id = '1`, I am able to delete all your table entries. Use PDO instead of mysql_ functions which are highly deprecated.

Comment: `mysql_`-functions are deprecated: http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php

Comment: I was aware that mysqli was a better option, which someone else in the group is just not going to worry about now. I'll have to fix that later. I'll definitely make those changes, but functionality is the most important at the moment. Having trouble finding the POST parameters in debug. Using Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this. But I will change your code from **MySQL** to **MySQLi**.

```
<?php

// Connects to your Database
session_start();
$x = $_SESSION['user'];
$y = $_GET['id'];

/* ESTABLISH CONNECTION */

$connect=mysqli_connect("YourHost","YourUsername","YourPassword","YourDatabaseName"); /* REPLACE THE NECESSARY HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, AND DATABASE */

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

echo "Error".mysqli_connect_error();
}

if (isset($_POST['delete'])){ /* IF DELETE IS SET/CLICKED */

   $counter=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['hiddencounter']);
   $checkbox=$_POST['checkbox'];

   for($x=0;$x<=$counter;$x++){

       if(!empty($checkbox[$x])){ /* IF SELECTED ITEM */

       $checked=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$checkbox[$x]);

       mysqli_query($connect,"DELETE FROM Student_has_Class WHERE User_idUser='$checked'"); 

       } /* END OF IF NOT EMPTY CHECKBOX SELECTED */

   } /* END OF FOR LOOP */

} /* END OF ISSET DELETE */

?>

<?php

$sql = "SELECT User.idUser, User.UserFirstName, User.UserLastName
FROM Student_has_Class
INNER JOIN User ON User.idUser = Student_has_Class.User_idUser AND User.Role = 'Student'
INNER JOIN Class ON Class.idClass = Student_has_Class.Class_idClass
WHERE Student_has_Class.Class_idClass = 2 AND Class.User_idUser = ".$x."
ORDER BY User.UserLastName";

$result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);

$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

?>

<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td><form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="4" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Class Roster</strong> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Drop</td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>ID</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Last Name</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>First Name</strong></td>
</tr>

<?php
$counter=0; /* FOR COUNTING PURPOSES */
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{ 
?>

<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<?php
$iduser=$rows['idUser'];
echo "<input name='checkbox[$counter]' type='checkbox' id='checkbox[]' value='$iduser'></td>";
/* I HAVE ASSIGNED THE COUNTER INSIDE THE CHECKBOX ARRAY ABOVE. AND DO YOU REALLY NEED [] IN YOUR ID? */ ?>

<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['idUser'];?></td>

<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['UserLastName'];?></td>

<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['UserFirstName'];?></td>
</tr>

<?php
$counter=$counter+1; /* INCREMENT COUNTER EVERY LOOP */
} /* END OF WHILE LOOP */

echo "<input type='hidden' name='hiddencounter' value='$counter'>"; /* SUBMIT A HIDDEN INPUT CONTAINING THE OVERALL COUNTER */

?>

<tr>
<td colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: I tried your code, removed the redirect stuff from my code too, which you didn't include either. After clicking Submit, it refreshes and shows the table of students with no students. I have to go to previous page and the students populate again. I tried without the square brackets in the ID, but same results. Take a look at the form code, the "action" parameter is set to NULL. Does this make sense?

Comment: What are you getting? See my updated answer. I've updated the assigning value to the checkbox.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for an answer for what I am getting. Now it just refreshes and doesn't show the table at all. I click "Back" and it goes back to the page, and the user isn't removed.

Comment: You have to make sure that you replace the necessary data for the SQLi connection I've made. And are you sure about the value of the checkbox? You set the value of each checkbox to idUser from User table (User.idUser). And delete FROM Student_has_Class table WHERE User_idUser=User.idUser, right?

Comment: I know the SQLi connection parameters are correct. Good idea about the  User_idUser. There was no change though when I made that change.

Comment: So I double checked that the SQL code works by running a query. The table repopulates now that I hard-coded the teacher's id (User_idUser in the SELECT query) once it refreshes. We will fix the session variables later, but the Delete function definately doesn't work.

Comment: Strange. I think of this why it doesn't work: Delete won't happen if the value of Student_has_Class.User_idUser didn't find any match with the values of User.idUser. And the code I have provided doesn't have <meta> or header(LOCATION:) to refresh the page or redirect to other page. I just use action='' in the <form> in order to submit the data into the page itself.

Comment: Double check your database if the User_idUser row in the table Student_has_Class has the same value with the idUser row of User table.

Comment: BTW, you try to delete data from Student_has_Class table, right? But your list of students data only came from the User table. So even if the delete is successful, you won't see the result in your list of students. You should check thoroughly your database. And proper database management would be better.

Comment: I got it so it passed a value to checkbox value now. I don't have the <meta> refresh anymore as I figured out that it wasn't necessary. fixed idUser, but no delete.

Comment: The user table has the user first name, etc. and the Student_has_Class is the table that stores what students are in each class by storing the classID and UserID in the Student_has_Class.

Comment: Check your Student_has_Class table. You won't see the result in your list of students output because you only try to delete data from Student_has_Class table, not in your User table.

Comment: Can you check first my updated answer? I've added a delete query inside the for loop.

Comment: We don't want to delete from the User table. That holds the accounts. Student_has_Class is just the class and the student's associated with that class. (intermediary table to avoid Many-to-Many between Class and User. please get my email down just in case so I can remove it from my profile about me description for privacy, and let me know.